# 針音ノ時計塔 or 時計塔ノ針音?

Tags: grammar, song-lyrics

I am referring to the lyrics of this vocaloid song: [Handbeat Clocktower](http://vocaloidlyrics.wikia.com/wiki/%E9%87%9D%E9%9F%B3%E3%83%8E%E6%99%82%E8%A8%88%E5%A1%94_(Shin%27on_no_Tokeitou))

I have the impression that the title (which also comes up in the lyrics) means "the handbeat of the clocktower" (or in other other words, the sound of the needle of the clocktower).

However, the corresponding の construction should be 時計塔の針音, so why is it reversed?

Does it perhaps imply that there is a handbeat that can be "universally" heard and that it comes from that clocktower as opposed to something else, i.e. the clocktower "of the handbeat"?

Or is there a grammatical explanation?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it means the clock tower is known for/named after the sound of its hand. Like the leaning tower of pisa is known for its leaning.

Answer (score 2):

針音ノ時計塔 grammatically means "Handbeat Clocktower" or "Clocktower of Handbeat". (Oh, I failed to find 'handbeat' in a dictionary, but let me assume 針音 means handbeat) And it's 時計塔の針音 that corresponds to "Handbeat of Clocktower".

"Xの塔" (tower of X) can mean many things:

- a tower made of X (material): 象牙の塔 = Tower of Ivory
- a tower in X (place): ハノイの塔 = Tower of Hanoi (city)
- a tower owned by X (person)
- a tower used for X (purpose): 試練の塔 = Tower of Trials
- a tower symbolized by/named after X: [太陽の塔 = Tower of the Sun](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tower_of_the_Sun); バベルの塔 = Tower of Babel (Babel is not the name of a city, but it means ['Gate of God'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tower_of_Babel#Etymology))

針音の時計塔 probably means the 針音 is the symbol of that 時計塔, just like 太陽の塔.